# How handle large amount of data in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have 17 store, 40K product, 100 category, 1000 attribute. Is Magento 2 support this much of data.? I need to speed up the website.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Listed Things

- Enable Flat Category
- Enable Flat Product
- Enable Cache
- Minify CSS
- Minify JS
- Bundle JS
- Use CDN if possible
- Try to use much less external jQuery
- Do image optimization if needed.
- Do leverage Browser Caching from .htaccess
- off eTag from .htaccess
- enable gzip from .htaccess

Hope this topics will increase your website speed.